# Getting Exception while migrating jboss version 6.4 to 7.2

Tags: jboss, migration, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

At the time of starting Jboss server I am getting below exception.

ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration

Note: I am doing Jboss migration from 6.4 to 7.2

Please help.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrage?

Comment: I believe you are using the same config file, which is not applicable. post the whole file, so we can see.